# ServiceStack, Oracle and EntityFramework

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm attempting to convert some old WCF web services to using ServiceStack and add some more functionality.

I need to connect to Oracle and use EntityFramework for the data access.

I've tried using the Oracle managed drivers with the ServiceStack.OrmLite.Oracle.Managed package and keep getting errors.

I took this demo: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1056/introducing-service-stack-tutorial

and modified it to use Oracle and having all kinds of issues.

Can anyone point me to some info on how to do this?

I modified the ormListConnectionFactory to this:

```
var ormLiteConnectionFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Oracle"].ConnectionString,
                                                                        OracleOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance);
```

And getting these 2 errors:

```
The type 'OrmLiteDialectProviderBase<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ServiceStack.OrmLite, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e06fbc6124f57c43'.
cannot convert from 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.Oracle.OracleOrmLiteDialectProvider' to 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.IOrmLiteDialectProvider'
```

Is there a way to not use the OrmLite and just use EF6, instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NuGet package for using OrmLite and Oracle is [ServiceStack.OrmLite.Oracle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Oracle). But if you don't want to use OrmLite, don't reference any OrmLite NuGet package or use its `OrmLiteConnectionFactory` class.

ServiceStack itself doesn't require any dependency to OrmLite, the error message you're getting is likely due to trying to mix and match using old 3rd Party NuGet package `ServiceStack.OrmLite.Oracle.Managed` which stops at version **v4.0.33** together with ServiceStack packages of a different version which you can't do - all ServiceStack NuGet packages should be the **same version**.

ServiceStack doesn't prohibit usage of EF6 - you should be able to use EF6 in the same way as you would any other .NET Project.

Comment: I changed to use the ServiceStack.OrmLite.Oracle package and now it doesn't show my service in the metadata.

Comment: @MB34 It's likely have a error on StartUp, can view by going to [?debug=requestinfo in DebugMode](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging#request-info)

Comment: startUpErrors is empty. I don't see anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: ooh, forgot to inherit my service:  `: Service`